# np.array() is not working when i gave a list including two ndarray with different shape

Tags: python, numpy

This is a code. I made a list  including two ndarray with different shape.

```
d = []

a = np.arange(183).reshape(3,61)
b = np.arange(51).reshape(3,17)

d = [a,b]

np.array(d)
```

Error is like below.

```
 File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.1.1\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "D:/dev/workspace/rl/test/npcopy.py", line 10, in <module>
    np.array(d)
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3,61) into shape (3)
```

np.copy() works when two ndarrays' first shpae are different. but if not, it is not working like above.

if I change this code as below,

```
import numpy as np

d = []

a = np.arange(183).reshape(4, 61)
b = np.arange(51).reshape(3, 17)

d = [a,b]

np.array(d)
```

it works!! so weird!!

Comment: Why not use just ```a+b```?

Comment: try: `np.concatenate(d, axis=1)`

Comment: Its expected. You cannot club two matrices of different dimensions into one n dimensional array

Comment: What resultant shape are you looking for? 3x78 ?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh I want it to be list including two ndarrays.

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh The type would be [ndarrry (3,61), ndarray(3,17)]

Comment: Then `d = [a,b]` is enough, why do `np.array(d)` ?

Comment: if that, this code run in function, so that it will be delivered as call by reference and needs to be executed as different value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try to make an array from arrays there are three possible results:

If the arrays have the same shape, the result is a higher dimension array:

```
In [295]: np.array((np.zeros((2,3),int),np.ones((2,3),int)))                 
Out[295]: 
array([[[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]],

       [[1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1]]])
In [296]: _.shape                                                            
Out[296]: (2, 2, 3)
```

If the arrays differ in shape, the result could be an object dtype array (similar to a `list`):

```
In [298]: np.array((np.zeros((2,3),int),np.ones((3,3),int)))                 
Out[298]: 
array([array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]]),
       array([[1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1]])], dtype=object)    # shape (2,)
```

But for some combinations of shapes, the result is an error:

```
In [301]: np.array((np.zeros((2,3),int),np.ones((2,4),int)))                 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-301-d67e6685581d> in <module>
----> 1 np.array((np.zeros((2,3),int),np.ones((2,4),int)))

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,3) into shape (2)
```

In the error case, the first dimensions match, just as in your first case.

Sometimes to create an object array you have to start with a 'empty' one, and fill it.  This is more reliable than the `np.array(...)` approach.

```
In [303]: arr = np.empty(2, object)                                          
In [304]: arr[:] = np.zeros((2,3),int),np.ones((2,4),int)                    
In [305]: arr                                                                
Out[305]: 
array([array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]]),
       array([[1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1]])], dtype=object)
In [306]: arr[:] = np.zeros((2,3),int),np.ones((2,3),int)                    
In [307]: arr                                                                
Out[307]: 
array([array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]]),
       array([[1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1]])], dtype=object)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! so this is a numpy bug? and you suggested workaround of it?

Comment: I wouldn't describe it as a bug.  The normal, expected behavior is the first case.   The others are, in a sense ways of making do with bad inputs.  I'd like to see `np.array` throw an error in both cases unless an object dtype was specified.  I suggested the most reliable way of making an object dtype array.

Answer (score 3):

As matrices are of different dimensions

```
> a = np.arange(183).reshape(3,61) b = np.arange(51).reshape(3,17)
> d=[np.array(a),np.array(b)] 
>  print(d) for output
> 
> or  d=[a,b]
>  np.concatenate(d, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using np.copy(), I chose to use copy.deepcopy(). It works even if the first shape of two items in list are same.